# CSS access columns in table

Tags: c#, html, css, gridview, webforms

I have html that is dynamically created when I bind my gridview to a data source. What i'm curious about is how can i use css to access an individual column and even individual cells? If i was manually creating the html i would put an id attribute in there but i'm able to because it's dynamically created when the program begins. Here is the html out put generated

```
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ContentPlaceHolderHome_GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Date</th><th scope="col">Project</th><th scope="col">Amount</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM</td><td>CTS</td><td>1000.99</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>2/1/2011 12:00:00 AM</td><td>ABC Company</td><td>1001.99</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1/3/2011 12:00:00 AM</td><td>CTS</td><td>1002.99</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>4/1/2011 12:00:00 AM</td><td>CTS</td><td>1003.99</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I also found out you can programmitcally add id's to each cell in a grid view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table has an id, so you can use that to access the elements inside that table.
For example, to select the second cell on the third row, you can use:

```
#ContentPlaceHolderHome_GridView1 tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2)
```

- The nth-child() selector is supported on all major browsers except IE8 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

My guess here would be that you would need to modify whatever is making the tables so that it adds some kind of class or id to those cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) property to define a css class name for the controls.